# Detect disconnected websocket in framework after navigation or page unload

Tags: javascript, websocket, safari, mobile-safari

I'm using a web framework where everything gets passed through a websocket. New / updated DOM elements are shipped over to the browser, events get shipped back to the server. Works great. Except when the websocket gets closed.

This happens...

- when using desktop/mobile Safari's browser navigation buttons are used to leave & come back to the page
- on mobile Safari after a timeout when switching to a different app, tab or screen locking
- when the WiFi goes down etc.

After that the user simply sees a normal looking page, but everything is obviously dead as no more updates happen and no more events get relayed to the server. I'd like to simply refresh the page in that case. Either everything goes back to normal or the user sees a connection error in case of no network etc.

I tried poking around in the framework's code, adding "window.location.reload(true);" to the "onclose" handler for the websocket kinda does the trick. My state is 100% on the server, so reloading the page will just fix things.

Assuming I can't modify / fix the web framework I'm using, and it doesn't have any onConnectionLost client-side event, what's my best option to detect this scenario and reload the page? Are there any events like 'onPageDisplayedButNotProperlyReloaded', 'onPageVisibleButHasBecomeStaleInTheMeantime', 'onWebSocketsClosed' for me to use? Can I just open some dummy websocket and reload the page when it gets closed or something? Any other good way to detect this?

Thanks!